# InnoDB tablespace critical

Tags: mysql, innodb

[image: Screenshot]

Could the error shown on the screenshot be the reason why my site is very slow?

If so, I really need help to fix it since I am far from being an engineer!

Comment: [This thread](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/munin-plugin-warn-mysql-innodb-free-tablespace.208591/) about *this* CPanel + Munin + InnoDb issue should set your mind at ease. The issue is caused by the way Munin counts free space....

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't think this is why your site is very slow.  You can change the alert levels by editing the following file:

```
vi /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/mysql_innodb
```

In this file you should see:

```
[mysql_innodb]
env.warning 2147483648
env.critical 1073741824
```

If the tablespace falls below either of these levels a warning or critical is raised.  Change these limits to whatever values (in bytes) you need. If you wish to completely disable this monitoring set the values to 0:

```
[mysql_innodb]
env.warning 0
env.critical 0
```

Restart munin:

```
/etc/init.d/munin-node restart
su munin -c /usr/bin/munin-cron
```

Comment: Copyright: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/munin-plugin-warn-mysql-innodb-free-tablespace.208591/#post-954962

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB stores data in a tablespace. By default, there is one single tablespace and data of all the databases is stored in one file. This file has data dictionary, tables, as well as indexes in it. There is a global parameter innodb_data_file_path that defines this tablespace file. It has a syntax like ibdata1:256M:autoextend, this means at the beginning a file of size 256 MB will be created and then whenever the data size exceeds this, the file will be auto-extended. The innodb_autoextend_increment variable defines in MB's that by how much each increment should be.

Reference link wherein it has mentioned in depth about InnoDB tablespace which can be helpful to you :
http://optimmysql.blogspot.in/2007/07/innodb-tablespace-size.html

Answer (score -1):

**According to [cPanel](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360053106374-Munin-shows-MySQL-InnoDB-free-tablespace-critical-alert), you should ignore this error.**

The linked page gives instructions on how to remove this indicator from Munin.

Comment: This is just a poorer version of an existing answer.